# Cannot update by clearcase in Eclipse or Clearcase Remote Client

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

[image: This is what it looks like in my eclipse.]

I work under a cloud environment, so all the configurations is same to others.

Where's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, delete a lock file like this .Systemfolder/lock. It is not exactly name. The name contains lock in it. I forget what exactly it is.

This will work.